# Internet Explorer CSS transition issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I have some elements which `width` changes to 0 with JS on scrolling and when transition `width` to 0 is beginning, elements firstly become very big, but then do as need. In Chrome all works perfectly.

Here is an example of this https://jsfiddle.net/dx914ut0/

What sholud I do?

UPD: Just need to add units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just transition try using the code below. This will make sure it works on every browser.

```
-webkit-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
-moz-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
-o-transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
transition: visibility 0s, opacity 2s ease-out;
```

Comment: but I need to animate `width` property

Comment: use width instead of visibility and opacity like this:

Comment: -webkit-transition: width 2s ease-out;

Answer (score 0):

try function onscroll in your html:

```
<div onscroll="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"></div>
```

except if you want this to happen on click, then you should probably add actionListiner or something.